# How to reduce downtime of table during inserts SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

I have an operative table, call it `Ops`. The table gets queried by our customers via a web service every other second.

There are two processes that affect the table:

1. Deleting expired records (daily)
2. Inserting new records (weekly)

My goal is to reduce downtime to a minimum during these processes. I know Oracle, but this is the first time I'm using SQL Server and T-SQL. In Oracle, I would do a truncate to speed up the first process of deleting expired records and a partition exchange to insert new records.

Partition Exchanges for SQL Server seem a bit harder to handle, because from what I can read, one has to create file groups, partition schemes and partition functions (?).

What are your recommendations for reducing downtime?

Comment: Table partitioning by a sliding window date range will allow you to purge expired data and load data incrementally by partition. You need a partition function and scheme but separate filegroups are not required. The partition scheme can specify the same filegroup for all partitions.

Comment: [Lock escalation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184286(v=sql.105).aspx) may also contribute to downtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A table is not offline because someone is deleting or inserting rows. The table can be read and updated concurrently.

However, under the default isolation level `READ COMMITTED` readers are blocked by writers and writers are blocked by readers. This means that a `SELECT` statement can take longer to complete because a not-yet-committed transaction is locking some rows the `SELECT` statement is trying to read. The `SELECT` statement is blocked until the transaction completes. This can be a problem if the transaction takes long time, since it appears as the table was offline.

On the other hand, under `READ COMMITTED SNAPSHOT` and `SNAPSHOT` isolation levels readers don't block writers and writers don't block readers. This means that a `SELECT` statement can run concurrently with `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE` statements without waiting to acquire locks, because under these isolation levels `SELECT` statements don't request locks.

The simplest thing you can do is to enable `READ COMMITTED SNAPSHOT` isolation level on the database. When this isolation level is enabled it becomes the default isolation level, so you don't need to change the code of your application.

```
ALTER DATABASE MyDataBase SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT ON
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I believe `READ COMMITTED SNAPSHOP` is what I need. I was hoping that INSERTS/DELETES don't block SELECT statements (or in other words... reads). I also read that the following option must be set on top of the one you mentioned at the bottom of your post:
`ALTER DATABASE <TableName> SET ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION ON`

Comment: @mpdegn. You don't  really need `ALTER DATABASE <DataBaseName> SET ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION ON`. This is for enabling SNAPSHOT isolation level which is not the same as READ COMMITTED SNAPSHOT isolation level.  To use SNAPSHOT isolation level you need to execute the statement: `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SNAPSHOT`. However if you enable READ COMMITTED SNAPSHOT, this became the default isolation level, so you don't need to do anything to use it.

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is "selects getting blocked,"  you can try 'NO LOCK' hint. But be sure to read the implications. You can check https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2470/understanding-the-sql-server-nolock-hint/ for details.